# When flowey pleads for mercy, does he really mean it?

Tags: undertale

I've been trying to do a Genocide Route but when I was about to have the chance to finish the Genocide Route, on a video I saw Flowey pleading for *mercy*, I don't know if he really meant it, if he did mean it, I would spare him by quitting the game and just abort the Genocide Route, but if he didn't mean it, then I would just let the game kill him and then complete the Genocide Route. Did he really mean the *mercy*?

Comment: I don't recall it ever being possible to spare Flowey in the Genocide Route in Undertale. BlueRaja's answer is from Unitale, not Undertale. Are you referring to Unitale or a different mod of Undertale?

Comment: @MBorg: Technically, you can "spare" him by quitting the game, as OP describes. IIRC the game doesn't really have any provision for this, however, and just treats it as if you had reset after defeating Sans (so you won't get any fascinating new dialog out of it).

Answer (score 1):

if you want to go through a genocide run, the only way to spare flowey is to quit. if you want to kill him, simply just watch. but if you wnt to spare him, you HAVE to leave the game. it will count as a reset and send you back to the menu, oh btw, i know a easter egg where if you name yourself "gaster" it sends you back to the intro.

Answer (score -1):

Yes Flowey does really mean it. The only way to spare him is to quit the game and reset. He realized that he’s not apart from the other monsters. He knows he will be killed, so he really means it when he pleads for mercy. But if your going for all endings you have to kill him for genocide route and soulless True Pacifist.